# Is there a Qt Widget to create Workspace Panes?

Tags: qt, widget

I'm looking (unsuccessfully) for a Qt widget that would work similarly to the panes in Eclipse IDE.  This inludes the ability to rearrange panes within the workspace.  Very powerful!  For instance, you can

- combine panes into tabs and separate them again
- place panes on the top, bottom, left, right or center.
- place panes under, over, within the left, and within the right of current panes
- pull panes into their on top-level window or re-integrate them into the main window
- double click a pane to take over the entire workspace or snap it back to its original position
- minimize a pane to a side bar
- etc!

Any idea if such a widget exists so I can create a workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdockwidget.html) would help.

Comment: Not enough points to vote up yet, but Thanks!  While I had no lucking finding this in the docs or tutorials, once I downloaded the QT sdk and demos, I was able to find this widget.  As you point out, the concept is a "dock" widget which can be put in a MainWindow.

Comment: @charliep You might accept this as the correct answer, however. Let me do the up-voting! :)